# What, if any, asymptotic arguments are used in moving between various statements of the central limit theorem?

Tags: asymptotics, central-limit-theorem

*What, if any, asymptotic arguments are used in moving between the various statements of the central limit theorem (e.g. in terms of sample means compared with standardised sample means)?*

**Context.**

My question is somewhat trivial, and perhaps pedantic, but I would appreciate some concrete insight on it in any case.

In terms of the asymptotic normality of sample means, one version of the central limit theorem is

$$\overline{X}_n \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{N} \left(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n} \right) \tag{1}$$

for i.i.d. $X_1, \dots, X_n$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. An equivalent formulation in terms of standardised sample means might be

$$\frac{ \sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n - \mu)}{\sigma} \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{N}(0,1). \tag{2}$$

Most intermediate statistics references I have seen prove $(2)$ using some assumptions about the moment generating function, and Taylor approximations. I have noticed that pedagogically, they either present:

- $(1)$ and $(2)$ as equivalent formulations of the same theorem.
- Or they prove $(2)$ and assume that in asymptopia, we can move from $(2)$ to $(1)$. No further, explicit justification for how we move between $(2)$ and $(1)$ is presented, possibly because it is so fundamental and "standard".

In the latter case, could we view going from $(2)$ to $(1)$ as an instance of the continuous mapping theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you take a limit $n \to\infty$ then $n$ cannot occur on the right hand side, the limit expression cannot depend on $n$.  So your $(1)$ is incorrect, while $(2)$ is the correct expression.

The way $(1)$ arises (but not as a limit, a an approximation) is that you decide that your $n$ is large enough to trust the CLT as an approximation. So you write
$$ \frac{ \sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n - \mu)}{\sigma} \overset{d}{\approx} \mathcal{N}(0,1). \tag{2} $$
where we have **replaced** $\overset{d}{\longrightarrow}$ by $\overset{d}{\approx} $, meaning *approximately distributed as*. Multiplying by $\sigma$ and dividing by $\sqrt{n}$ we then get
$$
   \overline{X}_n \overset{d}{\approx} \mathcal{N}(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}n)
$$
This does not involve any use of the continuous mapping theorem.  As a fact, from the point that we decide to use the CLT result as an approximation, there is no asymptotics involved.

Comment: +1. Thank you for assisting in clarifying some of my erroneous preconceptions.